# Removing the application of a macro from an expression

Tags: macros

How would I write macros `\firstArgument` and `\macroName` which would do the following:

```
\firstArgument{\bf{a}}    reduces to a
\macroName{\bf{a}}        reduces to bf
```

I am aware of the approach `\def\dismantle#1{{\let\Large\@firstofone #1}}` but it is not a solution for me since it only works for `\bf` whereas is am looking for macros doing this for all macros.

**Update:** As it became clear throughout the discussion, "firstArgument" only shall allude to the structure of what is meant here. Similarly `\bf` only serves as an arbitrary example. That is important, as TeX has no notion of argument when the definition of a macro is not (yet) known and the notion may depend on that definition.

Comment: `\bf` is not defined by default in latex, and when it is defined it does not take an argument, so the syntax would be `{\bf a}` not `\bf{a}`

Comment: Would it help in understanding what I want if I had written `\XYZ` above?

Comment: I'd have given the same answer as Phelype :-)

Comment: it seemed worth raising the bf syntax error as if your actual use case is to extract the font command and the styled text that would matter, if it was just `\xyz` you picked an unfortunate example since `a` isn't an argument of `\bf` so `\firstArgument` is a bad name.

Comment: My use case is to get the name of a macro and the first parameter of the macro. This should work for all situations and in fact using `\bf`as example was pretty much stupid from me since it is misleading.

Comment: @UlrichDiez That was one of my thoughts as well but I am not sure how to get a macro to accept `{` and `}` as delimiters. Probably some category code stuff but I was unable to get any meaningful results here. This inability brought me here :-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: What is wrong with `\bf{a}` from a syntax point of view? I realize you don't usually **do** things that way but isn't it a perfectly legal expression? Independently from the fact that it is bad style? My task is that I get, from a source I cannot control, expressions of this kind (rather of `{\bf{a}}`to be exact) and I have to dismantle them into parts.

Comment: @Nobody-Knows-I-am-a-Dog `\bf` has been deprecated for 25 years. If your source produces this rubbish, it's time to ask its maintainer to update it.

Comment: as I say by default `\bf` is not defined in latex. `article` class (not the latex format) declares it for compatibility with latex2.09 documents from the 1980s. When it is defined it does not take an argument. `\bf{a}bcd` is the same as `\bf abcd` and makes abcd all bold.

Comment: @Nobody-Knows-I-am-a-Dog it is like `\LaTeX` that does not take an argument, writing `\LaTeX{a}` does not suddenly mean that `a` is an argument of `\LaTeX`. The same is true of `\bf` but at least `\LaTeX` is defined in the format, `\bf` is not defined at all (try `scrartcl` class instead of `article` for example)

Comment: @egreg: Besides that there might be a reason that this was done like that - "ask the maintainer" works in an ideal world only. I have to be interoperable with what I get :-)

Comment: @UlrichDiez (and @DavidCarlisle) Strictly speaking we have no notion of "first argument" in `\LaTeX`as this depends on semantics as your example very nicely shows. I need this to work for structures of the **form** `{\XYZ{uvw}}`which we traditionally would call "first argument" without having to write down a Chomsky-0 grammar to make this more precise. And: It is merely a syntax issue. I do not need to have this restricted to specific or even defined macros. The accepted answer is a very fine solution.

Comment: @UlrichDiez and how would you deal with the situation if (1) for `\xyz`you had no macro-definition? (2) when you only later learned about delimiters, thus affecting the definition of a first parameter. (3) the parameters were not "primitives" but rather macros or higher order functions? I really do not see a chance to define this formally, which in my belief is the reason why we have no grammar for LaTeX but just a set of evaluation rules. If my belief is wrong I would be very much interested in a source - for completely different reasons than this here.

Comment: no there is a clear meaning for first argument, if you go `\def\zz#1{zzz}`  or `\newcommand\zz[1]{zzzz}` then `\zz` has an argument and `\zz{xyz}` xyz is the argument (and the braces delimit the argument.  But if you define `\def\zz{xxx}`  or `\newcommand\zz{xxx}` then in `\zz{xyz}`  `\zz` has no argument and the braces take on an entirely different syntactic role, they do not delimit an argument they from a group making a local scope for xyz. Saying that `{xyz}` is the argument of `\zz` in such a case is simply wrong.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That's exactly my line of reasoning. When you look at the string `\zz{xyz}`you cannot say that `xyz` is an argument. You only know that after consulting macro definitions (and, btw, cat codes), which might decide on that question. Thus "there is no notion of 'first argument'" which can be settled by a local look only. The name I gave to the macro in my question was misleading. I used it only as a (bad) allusion to what I want; actually I needed the connected reductions - whatever you call it. But: Good to be reminded of that aspect once in a while. Thnx.

Comment: @Nobody-Knows-I-am-a-Dog sure in the answer I (mostly) stuck to answering that, but in comments other issues were raised such as "why is \bf bad style" and also checking whether you did actually want to grab a real argument (to pre-process it before calling the original, say, in which case checking it is actually an argument may have been relevant:-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\firstArgument#1{\zza#1}
\def\macroName#1{\zzb#1}
\def\zza#1#2{#2}
\def\zzb#1#2{\expandafter\zzc\string#1}
\def\zzc#1{}
\begin{document}

\firstArgument{\bf{a}}

\macroName{\bf{a}}
   
\end{document}
```

[image]

note that `a` is not an argument of `\bf` here.

Comment: \zzc is the same as \@gobble? For eliminating the backslash

Answer (score 3):

As in TeX they are closely tied to the concepts of defining and expanding macros let's avoid the terms  "argument" and "parameter" completely and instead use the modified form of Backus/Naur-notation introduced for defining TeX's "parts of speech" in Chapter 24: Summary of Vertical Mode of the TeXbook:

If this is to be applied to the token-pattern

*⟨control sequence⟩⟨left brace⟩⟨balanced text⟩⟨right brace⟩*

- *⟨control sequence⟩* neither being an `\outer` token nor being an active character nor being the "nameless control sequence token" constructable via `\csname\endcsname` or via a single character of category code 0(escape), i.e., a backslash, at the not-commented end of a line of input while `\endlinechar`'s value is not positive
- *⟨balanced text⟩* not containing tokens defined in terms of `\outer`

only, while the `\escapechar`-parameter has its usual value 92(decimal):

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\firstArgument[1]{\@secondoftwo#1}%
\newcommand\macroName[1]{\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@gobble\expandafter\string\@firstoftwo#1}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\ttfamily\selectfont

\firstArgument{\textbf{a}}
 
\macroName{\textbf{a}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Cood edit of your answer. This is so much more precise in employed concepts.

Comment: @Nobody-Knows-I-am-a-Dog Thanks, but it wasn't sufficiently precise so I saw the need of doing another edit. ;-(